# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{r^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a general rule to find the value of infinite sums like $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{r^n}?$$ I know the formula for a sum of a geometric sequence, but this is a geometric sequence multiplied by an arithmetic sequence. How would one calculate this infinite sum?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) is a related question.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 1):

For $\displaystyle|y|<1, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^n=\frac1{1-y}$

Differentiate both sides wrt $y$ and multiply with $y$

Set $\displaystyle y=\frac1x$

See also :  [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Series.2C_sum_to_n_terms)

Comment: OR $y=\frac 1r$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, What is $r$ here?

Comment: It's the variable as used in the OPs question. There is no $x$ in the question.

Comment: @Downvoter, Please pinpoint the mistake

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Set $x = 1/r$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n = x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = x \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$$
where the last equality holds when $|x|<1$. Now use your geometric series knowledge.